# Group-Time interaction from MANOVA in R?

Tags: r, repeated-measures, manova

I'm practicing MANOVA with R. 
I have a data (perhaps famous) called 'rat-weight data.'

```
> rat
   w0 w1  w2  w3  w4
1  46 70 102 131 153
2  49 67  90 112 140
3  49 67 100 129 164
4  51 71  94 110 141
5  52 77 111 144 185
6  56 81 104 121 151
7  57 82 110 139 169
8  57 86 114 139 172
9  60 93 123 146 177
10 63 91 112 130 154
11 52 70 105 138 171
12 52 73  97 116 140
13 54 71  90 110 138
14 56 75 108 151 189
15 57 72  97 120 144
16 59 85 116 148 177
17 59 85 121 156 191
18 46 61  78  90 107
19 51 75  92 100 119
20 51 75 101 123 140
21 53 79 100 106 133
22 53 72  89 104 122
23 56 78  95 103 108
24 58 69  93 114 138
25 59 80 101 111 122
26 59 88 100 111 122
27 61 86 109 120 129
```

They are divided into three treatment groups.

```
> ratgroup <- gl(3, 9, 27, labels = c("control", "thyroxine", "thiouracil"))
> ratgroup
 [1] control    control    control    control    control    control   
 [7] control    control    control    thyroxine  thyroxine  thyroxine 
[13] thyroxine  thyroxine  thyroxine  thyroxine  thyroxine  thyroxine 
[19] thiouracil thiouracil thiouracil thiouracil thiouracil thiouracil
[25] thiouracil thiouracil thiouracil
Levels: control thyroxine thiouracil
```

They are weights of 27 rats 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 weeks after birth. This is a repeated measures design. My purpose is to extract effects of (1) treatment group, (2) time, and (3) treatment group-time interaction.

Using R, I made a `mlm` object.

```
> rat.mlm2 <- manova(rat %*% contr.poly(5) ~ ratgroup)
```

Results are simple.

```
> summary(rat.mlm2, test = "W", intercept = T)
            Df   Wilks approx F num Df den Df    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept)  1 0.02000  257.263      4     21 < 2.2e-16 ***
ratgroup     2 0.34827    3.646      8     42  0.002639 ** 
Residuals   24                                             
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I suppose that Wilks' Lambda 0.03000 is for the 'time effect,' and 0.34827 is for the 'treatment group effect.' Please help me finding the values for 'the group-time effect.'

Also, I like to know how MANOVA group-group multiple comparisons are obtained in R.

Comment: Some clarifications are needed. With contr.poly(5), are you interested in the linear up to quartic relationships across time? By 'group-time effect' do you mean the interaction effect in the conventional univariate (or ANOVA) sense, or whether the three groups have the same linear to quartic effects across time? What do you mean by "group-group multiple comparisons"?

Comment: I meant the interaction effect in the conventional ANOVA sense. (Can it be estimated in MANOVA?) 'Group-group multiple comparisons' are kinda post hoc multiple comparison, control-thyroxine, control-thiouracil, and thyroxine-thiouracil comparisons.

Comment: You didn't answer the first question: are you interested in comparing the four trend effects (linear up to quartic relationships) across time, or comparing the differences among the five time points?